# Update multiple rows with same ID in one table

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to update my table that have same id.

Design view:

[image]

Database Design:

[image]

Basically it is form where the user has to choose and then in the future, they can update it. However, I am not sure how can I update the value.

Let's say if currently there is 2 rows with `Scholarship_id = 1`. How can I update if the user decided to select 1, 3, 6?

```
DELETE FROM ScholarshipDiploma 
WHERE Scholarship_ID = '2';

UPDATE ScholarshipDiploma 
SET course = '1'
WHERE Scholarship_ID = '2';
```

but it will delete the whole rows of 2 and did not update.

Comment: You should provide more details as to what you have tried so far.

Comment: done please take a look

Comment: Some reason you can't just use `DELETE ScholarshipDiploma WHERE ScholarshipDiplomaID = '2'`?  That looks like it is the PK.

Comment: I think u overlooked. i used Scholarship_ID not ScholarshipDiplomaID

Comment: why not just execute the update? Why are you deleting?

Answer (score 0):

Your delete statement has the same where clause as your update statement, so if you execute the delete statement before the update statement, there are no rowd to update. I think you should delete first and then insert new rows.

```
INSERT INTO ScholarshipDiploma (Scholarship_id, course) values (1,1), (1,3), (1,6)
```